# 2 columns that resize based on the content in one of the divs

Tags: html, css

I know this may seem basic, but I am looking for the cleanest solution for this. I have a container DIV with 2 divs located inside of it. I need one to stay on the left and take up approximately 75% of the container, while the right takes up 25%....... but ONLY if there is content in the right div, if not the left div should take up 100% of the container.

What is the easiest, cleanest solution for this?

Comment: It is hard to give a solution without seeing your code and in what situation it is being used.

Comment: I just have a blank page that I'd like to place a 2 columns into. The left taking up 75% of page, unless there is no content in the right column, at which point the left takes up 100% of page.

Comment: You should try giving it a shot and post your attempt. Maybe try a jsfiddle or something? (People really appreciate when you've already given it an attempt)

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use `float`.

Example **with content** on the right:

```css
#right {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  background: red;
}

#left {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="right">
    right
  </div>
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
</div>
```

Example **without content** on the right:

```css
#right {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  background: red;
}

#left {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="right">
    
  </div>
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use flexbox and set the `min-width` of the left container to `75%`:

```css
.container {
  padding:20px;
  background-color:black;
  display:flex;
  color:white;
}

.left {
  flex:1;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  min-width:75%;
}

.right {
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    totot
    tototo
    tititi
    tototot
    tototoot
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    to
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>
```